# Laravel 5.2 Does not show errors in register

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I add my routes in `web middleware`.
When I post `null` value in register, it does not show me validation errors.
But when I remove `web middleware` from my route it works correctly.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
      Route::auth();
}
```

it does not work, but

```
Route::auth();
```

works correctly

Kernel.php

```
    protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
      \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,   ### redirect if Authenticate
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
      //  \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,

    ],
```

Comment: Please include your `app/Http/Kernel.php` full file

Answer (score 0):

U should use this in your middle-were (if u are trying to use it in middle-were)-

```
return redirect()->route('auth');
```

Worked for me.

---

If u want to do that in view, then u can try this-

```
route('my_route_name');
```

Or

```
URL::to('foo');
```

Or,

url('foo');

If u want to use in **route.php** then an example is given in here-

> https://github.com/abrarjahin/laravel_5.2_form_handeling/blob/master/app/Http/routes.php

More can be found in-

1. https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#named-routes
2. https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#defining-middleware

Comment: My problem is web middleware in laravel 5.2 not define middleware.