# Get column list with Eloquent relation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I want to get column list with Eloquent relation in laravel.
When I use this comman

```
 $columns = Schema::getColumnListing('news');
```

Result is all fields of news table but I want to get relation fields for CategoryNews table.

News model:

```
public function NewsCategories()
   {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\CategoryNews');
   }
```

CategoryNews model:

```
public function News()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\News');
  }
```

Comment: Can't you just change it from `'news'` to `'news_categories'` or whatever your table is called?

Comment: No I want get all relationa and dynamic . this is manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
$columns = Schema::getColumnListing($news->NewsCategories()->getRelated()->getTable()));
```

Using `getRelated()` method you are getting related object for relationship (in your case it's `App\CategoryNews`) and now using method `getTable()` you can get table name for this model and you can use this table name for `getColumnListing()` method.

Comment: thanks please see this post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36257730/laravel-5-2-does-not-show-errors-in-register